# windows.h alternative for mac os

Tags: windows, macos, file, header

Good morning,
I am programming in Codeblock c program. However, I need use **windows.h** and **conio.h**. This header files are not on MacBook. Please, can you help me?  Source which doesn't work:

```
void gotoxy (int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord; // coordinates
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y; // X and Y coordinates
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

gotoxy(xn, yn);
```

Thank you for answer.

Comment: `SetConsoleCursorPosition` is Windows API, available on Windows only. Find the Mac equivalent

Comment: The `<curses.h>` header and corresponding `-lcurses` or `-lncurses` libraries provide screen management functions (with different names and calling conventions) in the Unix style, and even a `getch()` function.  However, `<windows.h>` and `<conio.h>` provide many other functions which are not covered by `<curses.h>` — and there is no direct analogue for many of the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ANSI escape sequences. They are not as nice as the windows.h functions, but they seem to do the trick.

[This link](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) takes you to a full table of escape sequences, and [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) takes you to the wikipedia page that explains it more deeply. The one you want is `Esc[Line;ColumnH` or `Esc[Line;Columnf`. Esc is the written literally as `"\033"`, and Line and Column are numbers that specify where the cursor position will be. A simple example:

```
printf("\033[0;0H"); // Sets cursor to (0,0)
printf("Hello World");
printf("\033[0;0HJ"); // writes a J at (0,0), now says "Jello World!"
```

To rewrite your function you could do:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", y, x);
}
```